# Why Apache's .htaccess 301 redirect doesn't work if having /opt keyword in URL?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

Trying to redirect urls:

**Doesn't work:**

```
Redirect 301 /newsDetail/opto-circuits-selected-to-supply-medical-devices-to-chicago-transit-systems http://www.google.com/
```

**Works if changed opto to opso:**

```
Redirect 301 /newsDetail/opso-circuits-selected-to-supply-medical-devices-to-chicago-transit-systems http://www.google.com/
```

***key points***

1. Using Linux server
2. Using PHP with Codeigniter

I am successfully redirecting 50 other urls in my .htaccess file and everyone works like charm except this.

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work"?

Comment: @sємsєм The page doesn't do a 301 redirect to Google, I would assume.

Comment: In other words, could the `newsDetail/opto-circuits...` accessed correctly without any errors? It seems that you have performed codeIgniter route changes.

Answer (score 0):

If there is nothing specifically in your site configuration which would seem responsible for this, it's quite possible that your web host has server-wide configuration in place (such as web application firewall rules) which are blocking this URL. Contact them for details.